# Trouble with a recursive method

Tags: java, arrays, recursion

```
public static boolean array6(int[] nums, int index) {
    if(nums.length > index+1) 
    {
        if(nums[index] == 6)
            return true;
        else
            array6(nums,index+1);
    }
    else if(nums.length==index+1)
    {
        if(nums[index] == 6)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
    return false;
}
```

As a part of an exercise for my CSA class we have to write a method that finds whether or not a 6 is present in an int array and returns the corresponding boolean value. The method I wrote works if the first number in the array is a 6, but it doesn't otherwise. Why?

Note: Has to be done recursively

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are not firing a recursion since nowhere inside your code you are returning the result of the method itself. Rewriting the content of the `if statement` that is executed if the condition is `true` as follows would make it work as intended:

```
if (nums.length > index_next) 
{
    if (nums[index] == 6)
        return true;

    // you have to return the result of the function here
    // in order to obtain an effective recursion, otherwise the
    // method is called but it's output value is ignored and the
    // functions goes outside the scope of the if statement
    // reaching the "return false" located at the bottom
    return array6(nums, index_next);
}
```

But overall, your function contains a lot of problems. Your task is very simple, but you are coding it in an extremely complex way. There are plenty of built-in functions you could use in order to achieve the same result... and even if you don't want to use them, a simple `for loop` would do the job:

```
boolean found = false;

for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; ++i)
{
    if (nums[i] == 6)
    {
        found = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

**EDIT: RECURSIVE IMPLEMENTATION**

```
public static boolean array6(int[] nums, int index)
{
    if (index == nums.length)
        return false;

    if (nums[index] == 6)
        return true;

    return array6(nums, index + 1);
}
```

Comment: forgot to mention that it had to be done recursively mb

Comment: I edited my answer to provide a recursive implementation :)

Answer (score 0):

A compact solution

```
bool array6(int* array, int len, int index) {

    if (index == len) {
        return false;
    }

    return array[index] == 6 || array6(array, len, index + 1);

}
```